# Is there a canonical book on creating highly interactive websites (eg. "Flash" like) with HTML5/CSS3/JS/jQuery?

Tags: web-development, javascript, books, jquery, html5

I know some of the basics of these technologies already, but it is mostly limited to more static sites. Using things like HTMl5 semantic elements, CSS3 gradients, shadows, `@font-face` etc.

Is there a book out there that's the de-facto standard for describing best practices, design methodologies, and other helpful information on creating highly interactive websites with HTML5/CSS3/JS/jQuery? What about that book makes it special?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `<canvas>` examples in:

- HTML5 Rocks -- http://www.html5rocks.com/
- Dive into HTML5 -- http://diveintohtml5.org/

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of books available about HTML5 and CSS3

These are some of the books, I know of which may help to armed your knowledge to create highly interactive websites, I reckon.

- HTML5 Canvas By Steve Fulton, Jeff
  Fulton
- HTML5: Designing Rich Internet
  Applications (Visualizing the Web) By
  Matthew David
- HTML5: Up and Running By Mark Pilgrim

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using AJAX to make a page more application like.  This way you can utilize the power of server-side technology while still using html/css and such.  The best intro books I've found on programming languages have been the missing manual series if you can find the language your looking for in that series.  Their CSS Missing Manual is great!  Also so much information and tutorials are available online and are only a google search away.